# Creating a custom Angular filter with TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, filter, typescript

I'm trying to work out the best way of creating a custom Angular Filter with TypeScript.

All the code samples I see use something like:

```
myModule.filter( "myFilter", function()
{
    return function( input )
    {
        //  filter stuff here
        return result;
    }
}
```

... which works, but seems messy as I want to keep all my filter code separate. So I want to know how to declare the filter as a separate file (eg filters/reverse-filter.ts) so I can create it like:

```
myModule.filter( "filterName", moduleName.myFilter );
```

... the same way you would for Controllers, Services etc.

The documentation for TS and Angular together seems pretty thin on the ground, especially where filters are concerned - can anyone help out?

Cheers!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Functions can be exported from modules like this:

```
module moduleName {
    export function myFilter()
    {
        return function(input)
        {
            //  filter stuff here
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

then outside the module:

```
myModule.filter("filterName", moduleName.myFilter);
```

Then it would then be possible to do things like automatically register all of the filters defined in the `moduleName` module by iterating over its public properties.

Comment: Can the myFilter function take arguments? I've not really used Angular, so I can't help you out there.

Answer (score 23):

Maybe too late but can be useful for someone else.

```
module dashboard.filters{

    export class TrustResource{

        static $inject:string[] = ['$sce'];

        static filter($sce:ng.ISCEService){

            return (value)=> {
                return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(value)
            };
        }
    }
}     
    dashboard.Bootstrap.angular.filter('trustAsResourceUrl',dashboard.filters.TrustResource.filter);
```

To explain the last line:

```
dashboard.Bootstrap.angular.filter('trustAsResourceUrl',dashboard.filters.TrustResource.filter);)
```

I will add a piece of code, wich represents my Bootstrap class, so you can understand it.

```
module dashboard {
    export class Bootstrap {

        static angular:ng.IModule;

        static start(){        
            Bootstrap.angular = angular.module('EmbApp', dashboard.Bootstrap.$inject);
        }


    }
}

//run application
dashboard.Bootstrap.start();
```

If you need more information about how it works, you can checkout my own TypeScript/AngularJS/Less structure [here](https://github.com/Dazag/angularjsSeed)

Comment: Thank you. What if I have multiple filters and want to have them in separate files/classes. Will each "module dashboard.filters{" overwrite the other?

Comment: No, they don't overwrite. You'll have access to all of them. I actually use that approach to structure my project. If I have UserController Class and UserService class, both of them rely under dashboard.user{ }

Comment: I got the error message `is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode` are you sure you can inject it the way you do?

Comment: do you do strict mode? It sounds like there is some incompatibility between the code and strict mode.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example using the injector to get dependencies into your filter. This one gets injected with the $filter service.

```
export class CustomDateFilter {
    public static Factory() {
        var factoryFunction = ($filter: ng.IFilterService) => {
            var angularDateFilter = $filter('date');
            return (theDate: string) => {
                return angularDateFilter(theDate, "yyyy MM dd - hh:mm a");
            };
        };

        factoryFunction.$inject = ['$filter'];

        return factoryFunction;
    }
}

// and in the bootstrap code:
app.filter('customDate', your.module.CustomDateFilter.Factory());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like this to inject dependencies

```
   myModule.filter('filterName', ['$http', moduleName.myFilter]);
```

Comment: I up-voted your answer as I came here first... but there is a better explanation on injecting dependencies here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264582/typescript-how-to-utilize-angular-filter-within-custom-filter

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter using class with a static function.

```
export class FilterClass
{
 static id = "FilterId"; //FilterName, use while consume

 /*@ngInject*/
 public static instance() { //static instance function
    let dataFilter  = () => {
        let filteredObject = () => {
            //filter logic
             return filteredData;
        }
        return filteredObject;  
    }
    return dataFilter;
}   
}
//Module configuration 
angular.module(myModule).filter(FilterClass.id, FilterClass.instance());
```

Consume this filter in the controller using below way.

```
 let FilterFun:any = this.$filter('FilterId');
 let Filteroutput = FilterFun();
```