# Typescript: How to utilize angular $filter within custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, typescript

How can I utilize angular $filter within a custom filter? How to inject $filter dependency?

```
module Filters {

    export class CustomFilter {
        public static Factory() {
            return function (input:<any>) {

                var result = [];

                //Would like to utilize $filter.('filter') here

                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    angular.module('app')
        .filter('customFilter', [CustomFilter.Factory]);
}
```

Comment: @PSL Thanks a lot, it did resolve the issue. Also it would be great if you can further clarify what you mean by `//Here use $filter or filterFilter itself` . I utilized this successfully:  `//public static Factory($filter: ng.IFilterService)`

Comment: @PSL FYI your stackoverflow linkedin link is broken points to wrong address.

Comment: Yes what i meant is if you are using `$filter('filter')` to get the built in fiter function you could as well inject `filterFilter` instead of `$filter`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just inject `$filter` and use type `ng.IFilterService` or specifically use `filterFilter` (if you are looking for `$filter('filter')`) and use type `Function`.

```
module Filters {
    export class CustomFilter {
        //Here use `$filter` or filterFilter itself
       //public static Factory($filter: ng.IFilterService)
        public static Factory(filter:Function) {
            return function (input:any) {

                var result = [];

                //filter is now $filter('filter')

                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    angular.module('app')
        .filter('customFilter', ['filterFilter', CustomFilter.Factory]);
        //Inject $filter for generic filter getter
}
```