# ng-repeat custom filter not working (angular + typescript app)

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I am working on an angular application using typescript and trying to filter an ng-repeat using a custom filter. I was able to make it work using a jQuery function as filter, but I would like to have the function done in Typescript. Any ideas how I could migrate this function into a typescript function and keep the filter working?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="playground" ng-controller="PlaygroundCtrl as c">
    <br />
    <div>Filter: <input type="text" ng-model="c.filterText" /></div>
    <br />
    <div ng-repeat="person in c.people | filterPeople:c.filterText">
        {{person}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
angular.module("playground", []);

class PlaygroundCtrl {
    filterText: string;
    people: string[];

    constructor() {
        this.people = ["tom", "john", "gonzalo", "bruno"];
    }

    filterPeople(par: any) {
        return this.people;
    }
}

angular
    .module('playground')
    .controller('PlaygroundCtrl', PlaygroundCtrl)
    .filter('filterPeople', function () {
        return function (people, filter) {
            var filtered = [];
            angular.forEach(people, function (person) {
                if (filter != 'x') {
                    filtered.push(person);
                }
            });
            return filtered;
        };
    });
```

Comment: Does it still not work after your changes?

Comment: Also, I did investigation (in scope of you code before changes) and I found some interesting things. If interesting - I can put somewhere (comments, answer).

Comment: Example of implementing a filter in typescript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119557/creating-a-custom-angular-filter-with-typescript

Comment: The code is working now but as you can see above it is not using a typescript fitler. I will try that example later to see if I can get it to work. Thanks